# Textbox Blinker not coming in Titanium Alloy App

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I am learning Titanium, and today I created a new Alloy Project in Titanium Studio, but on Screen when I got textbox, then in emulator, textbox is showing but no blinker. Any method to show blinker?

Comment: this is the problem with some titanium SDKs, try applying theme. that worked for me.

Comment: textbox? Blinker? Show some code please and explain what should work and what doesn't